# Alternative to multiple concats in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, sqlperformance

I have a huge query like this:

```
SELECT 'Tipification', COUNT(*) TOTAL, to_char(INITDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM (
    SELECT (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM ) Triplet, INITDATE 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE USER IS NOT null 
        AND (INITDATE >= TO_DATE('2016-12-01 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
        AND (INITDATE <= TO_DATE('2016-12-31 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 

        AND ( (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) = 'aaa \ bbb \ ccc' 
            OR (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) = 'aaa \ bbb \ ddd' 
            OR (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) = 'xxx \ yyy \ zzz' 
            OR (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) = 'qqq \ www \ eee'
            ... etc ...
)
GROUP BY to_char(INITDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Where it go to more 300 string concatenations of this: `(TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) = '... \ ... \ ...'`.

When performing this query, I'm getting some core dumps since it is too expensive to DB to execute.

Is there any alternative way to perform a query like this without having the DB running out of memory?

Comment: Why not do the concatenation in an inline view or CTE instead of repeating it? Or use `in` to compare the individual columns instead of looking at the concatenated values? (Seems odd to get a memory error from that, but presumably you've ruled out other causes, and have a small memory target?)

Comment: Would `and type in (list of types) or subtype in (list of subtypes) or problem in (list of problems)` be logically sound?

Comment: `AND ( (TYPE || ' \ ' || SUBTYPE || ' \ ' || PROBLEM) IN  ('aaa \ bbb \ ccc', 'aaa \ bbb \ ddd' , 'xxx \ yyy \ zzz', 'qqq \ www \ eee')` ?

Comment: It looks to me that the TYPE/SUBTYPE/PROBLEM is a missing entity/table.  I would re-evaluate the design

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle has a nice `in` function that allows you to put in multiple column combos.

```
select to_char(INITDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(*)
from table
where user is not null
AND (INITDATE >= TO_DATE('2016-12-01 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND (INITDATE <= TO_DATE('2016-12-31 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
and (type, subtype, problem) in (
    ('aaa','bbb','ccc'),
    ('aaa','bbb','ddd')) --  ... etc
group by to_char(INITDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: A query that used to take almost 3 seconds, decreased to less than 1 second. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

`SAP HANA DB` alternative for concate query:

```sql
select * from table_name
  WHERE (col_name1,col_name2,col_name3)
  IN (('value1','value2','value3'),.....);
```

Similarly, one use this in an update and delete query as well.